# Remove outer border spacing and keep inner border space and ensure that middle div remains certain size

Tags: html, css

Hopefully someone can help me. I need to ensure that the left transparent background stays at 50% and re-sizes automatically, and I also need to ensure that the blue middle div has a fixed width of 328px (no matter what screen resolution). The far right div needs to stay flesh against the right side of the page, and adjust automatically.

I decided to use a table cell for the divs and put border spacing around the cell but I just wanted spacing between the divs. Adding the border spacing around the divs I now have 10px on the left and right side of the table.

So what am I doing wrong and how can I achieve the result that I look for? I'm open to changing my code if you feel that its not the best option for what I'm trying to achieve.

Here's the code that I have now (I changed the background colors so that you can see the boxes and the border spacing):http://jsfiddle.net/7we2H/8/

```
<div class="headercontent">

  <div id="mid_lft">LEFT DIV</div><!--mid_lft-->
  <div id="mls">MID DIV</div><!--mls-->
  <div id="mid_rht">RIGHT DIV</div><!--mid_rht-->

</div><!--header_content-->


.headercontent{width:100%; height:213px; display:table; position:relative; border- spacing:10px; margin:0 auto;}<br/><br/>
.headercontainer{position:relative;}

.headercontent > div{display:table-cell; height:213px; border:0px !important;}<br/><br/>
.mid_lft{background:#f03; width:50%; margin-right:10px;}<br/><br/>
.logo{ position:relative; float:right; top:40px; right:29px;}<br/><br/>
.mls{background:#36F; width:50px; margin-right:10px;}
.mid_rht{background:#f03; width:25% }
```

And here also a link to what is being put out by the code that I already have: http://evansmithrealestate.com/home.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the borders by adding `border-collapse: collapse` to `.headercontent`. Additionally, you can also add `table-layout: fixed` in order to set the width on the middle element.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jpWz3/)

```
.headercontent {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
#mls {
    width:328px;
}
```

---

If you want to keep the inner borders, you could always add a `border-left` to each element and then remove the `border-left` of the first `div` element:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ULeAq/)

```
.headercontent > div {
    display:table-cell;
    height:213px;
    border-left:10px solid #fff;
}
.headercontent > div:first-child {
    border:none;
}
```

---

If you need the borders to be transparent, then you will have to add a negative `margin-left` value equal to the `border-spacing` property - in this case, `margin-left:-10px`. You will then need to give the table a width of `100%` + 2 ***** `border-spacing`. You could therefore use [**`calc()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc): `width:calc(100% + 20px)`. Make sure to hide the overflow of the parent element too.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qWLgd/)

```
.headercontent {
    width:calc(100% + 20px);
    display:table;
    border-spacing:10px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin-left:-10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Josh! I did what you suggested, but now the 10px inner space between the divs have disappeared. How do I keep the inner space, and just remove the outer space? Here's an updated link of how it looks now: (http://evansmithrealestate.com/home.php)

Comment: Almost there that's just what I wanted but can the color be transparent instead of white for the color? I have an image in the background.

Comment: @jellybeans87 Alright, didn't notice that. Here is an [alternative solution](http://jsfiddle.net/qWLgd/).. it is relatively hackish. Add `margin-left:-10px` to `.headercontent`.. then change `width:100%` to `width:calc(100% + 20px)`. Additionally, you will need to add `overflow:hidden` to the `.header` element.

Comment: Thank you so much Josh! You're awesome! Does this hack work with the IE? I use chrome and haven't tested in other browsers yet.

Comment: @jellybeans87 This is the support of `calc()` - http://caniuse.com/calc That being said, your website looks fine in IE11/IE10/IE9.. I just tested it.